# Disassemble ActiveX-Control in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, activex

a short ActiveX-newbie question.
I want to disassemble a loaded ActiveX-Control.
How can I find the associated file for this Control? (Normally an ocx-File?)

In the "Manage Add-ons" overview of the IE the relevant ActiveX-Control is listed, but I can not find any file informations.

Thanks for respond!
Normen

Answer (score 0):

In my IE (version 11) when I click Manage Add-ons I see this.

[image]

Comment: Hi Pepo,
File and Folder properties are empty.

Comment: Sorry, File is not empty.
File is "mscoree.dll" and Folder is empty.
mscoree.dll seems to be a file for the .NET Environment.
Are there other places to find "logic" for ActiveX-Controls rather than dll or ocx-files?

Answer (score 0):

After a little google research and the friendly advice from Pepo, I found out that the ActiveX-Component is a .NET-Assembly. (Identifiable by the referenced file mscoree.dll in the Add-On overview in IE.)
I searched the name of the ActiveX-Control in the GAC and found the assembly and the dll.